# SPARQL - getting amounts of optional data and combining rows

Tags: sparql

I want to request the amounts of rooms in a venue:
This is what i get:

```
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/3>     -
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/ajax-foyer>    -
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/ajaxbalkon>    -
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/bovenzaal>     -
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/foyer>     -
ah:room     <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/room/grote-repetitielokaal>
```

Next to that I want to get a multiline return.

```
ah:attachment   <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/attachment/1>   -
ah:attachment   <http://data.artsholland.com/venue/04df157e-fc47-4448-83ed-d0a8c577d7dd/attachment/2>
```

I've allready searched  to realize this. Found  the group_concat solution, but I couldn't figure it out.

[my used query in the sparql browser](http://api.artsholland.com/sparql?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fvenue+%3Fgeometry+%3FopeningHours+%3FhomePage+%3FshortDescription+%3Ftitle+%3FvenueType+%3Flat+%3Flong+%3FpublicTransportInformation++%3Ftelephone+%3Femail+%3Fattachment+%3Froom%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fartsholland%2F1.0%2FVenue%3E+.%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3AopeningHours+%3FopeningHours+.%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09+%3Fvenue+foaf%3Ahomepage+%3FhomePage+.+%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3AshortDescription+%3FshortDescription+.+%0D%0A%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3AvenueType+%3FvenueType+.+%0D%0A%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+%09dc%3Atitle+%3Ftitle.%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+geo%3Alat%09%3Flat+.+%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+geo%3Along%09%3Flong+.+%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3ApublicTransportInformation+%3FpublicTransportInformation+.%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3Atelephone+%3Ftelephone+.+%09%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09OPTIONAL+%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%3Fvenue+ah%3Aemail+%3Femail+.+%09%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fvenue+ah%3Aattachment+%3Fattachment.%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL%7B%7B%0D%0A%09%09%3Fvenue+ah%3Aroom+%3Froom.%0D%0A%09%09%7D%7D%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%3Fvenue+geo%3Ageometry+%3Fgeometry+.++%0D%0AFILTER+%28search%3Adistance%28%3Fgeometry%2C+%22POINT%284.890+52.3764%29%22%5E%5E%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Frdf.opensahara.com%2Ftype%2Fgeo%2Fwkt%3E%29+%3C+2000+%2a+0.00000898315284%29+.%0D%0A%23+UTC%21+Dus+tijdsverschil+met+Nederlandse+tijd%21%21%21+%0D%0A%23+Daar+moet+je+dus+even+rekening+mee+houden+MARTIJN%21%0D%0A%0D%0A+%7D+ORDER+BY+%3Fvenue+&api_key=9cbce178ed121b61a0797500d62cd440&selectoutput=browse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the amount of rooms, use a `COUNT` operator. You should use this in combination with a `GROUP BY` clause, this tells the operator which results to aggregate together. For example:

```
SELECT ?venue (COUNT(?room) as ?nrOfRooms)
WHERE { 
        ?venue a ah:Venue ;
               ah:room ?room . 
}
GROUP BY ?venue
```

The `GROUP_CONCAT` works pretty similarly actually. I haven't looked in detail at your query, so this may not quite correspond with what the actual data looks like, but roughly, what you do is the following:

```
SELECT ?venue (GROUP_CONCAT(?attach) as ?attachments)
WHERE { 
        ?venue a ah:Venue ;
               ah:room ?room ;
               ah:attachment ?attach . 
}
GROUP BY ?venue
```

As for aggregating over a variable that is inside an OPTIONAL clause, that should make no difference.

Comment: When I try to put the same logic to my query, it doesn't work: SELECT DISTINCT ?venue (COUNT(?room) as ?nrOfRooms) ?geometry ?openingHours ?homePage ?shortDescription ?title ?venueType ?lat ?long ?publicTransportInformation  ?telephone ?email ?attachment 
WHERE {
 ?venue a <http://purl.org/artsholland/1.0/Venue> ;
               ah:room ?room .
 OPTIONAL {{
 ?venue ah:openingHours ?openingHours
     FILTER(langMatches(lang(?openingHours), "en")) .
  }}

Comment: "it doesn't work"? What errors do you get? What output did you expect, and what did you actually get? Also: please edit/update your original question with these additional details, so you can properly format it, rather than just copy/pasting into a comment. It's easier to read that way.

Comment: Just as a small pointer: the query you paste here doesn't have a GROUP BY clause, which, as I explained in the answer, you need to direct the aggregation.